# Find text height of TextLayout component

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Does anyone know if there is a way to find the height of the text within the TextLayout class?

I am making my TextLayout objects like so:

```
        this._textFlow = new TextFlow();
        this._paragraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
        this._textFlow.addChild(this._paragraphElement);

        this._span = new SpanElement();
        this._span.text = this._text;
        this._paragraphElement.addChild(this._span);
        if(this._textAlign != ''){
            this._paragraphElement.textAlign = this._textAlign;
        }

        var tempTextWidth:Number;
        var tempTextHeight:Number;
        if(this._textWidth > 0){
            tempTextWidth = this._textWidth;
        } else {
            tempTextWidth = NaN;
        }
        if(this._textHeight > 0){
            tempTextHeight = this._textHeight;
        } else {
            tempTextHeight = NaN;
        }

        this._containerController = new ContainerController(this, tempTextWidth, tempTextHeight);
        this._textFlow.flowComposer.addController(this._containerController);
        this._textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
```

All the public properties I'd expect to find the height are undefined such as this._textFlow.lineHeight.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: It may need to be displayed once before the height-related properties get values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/FlowElement.html#lineHeight), lineHeight is undefined by default, and a value of undefined means the line height is 120% of the text height. Text height is determined by the [fontSize](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/FlowElement.html#fontSize) property, which is also undefined by default, meaning the text height is 12.

Assuming both are undefined in your application, the height of each line should be 1.2 * 12 = 14.4. Disclaimer: I have never actually worked with the Text Layout Framework and don't know how reliable this information is.